# set HTML5 range input arrow to left corner

Tags: html, input

I am using HTML5 input="range",

By default the arrow is set in the middle I what it to start it from left.

This is my code.

```
<input id="test" type="range" min="1" max="10">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set value for it `value="0"`

It will be like this

```
<input id="test" type="range" value="0" min="1" max="10">
```

Comment: Well, although it seems to work this HTML is wrong and only works because the browsers do some sanitation work here. If min is 1, then value should be also 1 not 0.